# LED matrix on Raspberry PI multi-line?

Tags: python, argparse, led, raspberry-pi-zero

I have a python script but i want to add more lines.  How can I go about doing this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Display a runtext with double-buffering.
from samplebase import SampleBase
from rgbmatrix import graphics
import time


class RunText(SampleBase):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RunText, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.parser.add_argument("-t", "--text", help="The text to scroll on the RGB LED panel", default="I love you!")

    def run(self):
        offscreen_canvas = self.matrix.CreateFrameCanvas()
        font = graphics.Font()
        font.LoadFont("../../../fonts/7x13.bdf")
        textColor = graphics.Color(255, 255, 0)
        pos = offscreen_canvas.width
        my_text = self.args.text

        while True:
            offscreen_canvas.Clear()
            len = graphics.DrawText(offscreen_canvas, font, pos, 10, textColor, my_text)
            pos -= 1
            if (pos + len < 0):
                pos = offscreen_canvas.width

            time.sleep(0.05)
            offscreen_canvas = self.matrix.SwapOnVSync(offscreen_canvas)


# Main function
if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_text = RunText()
    if (not run_text.process()):
        run_text.print_help()
```

I tried adding another `self.parser.add_argument` but that did not work.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Display a runtext with double-buffering.
from samplebase import SampleBase
from rgbmatrix import graphics
import time


class RunText(SampleBase):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RunText, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.parser.add_argument("-t", "--text", help="The text to scroll on the RGB LED panel", default="I love you!")
self.parser.add_argument("-t", "--text", help="The text to scroll on the RGB LED panel", default="Will you marry me?")

    def run(self):
        offscreen_canvas = self.matrix.CreateFrameCanvas()
        font = graphics.Font()
        font.LoadFont("../../../fonts/7x13.bdf")
        textColor = graphics.Color(255, 255, 0)
        pos = offscreen_canvas.width
        my_text = self.args.text

        while True:
            offscreen_canvas.Clear()
            len = graphics.DrawText(offscreen_canvas, font, pos, 10, textColor, my_text)
            pos -= 1
            if (pos + len < 0):
                pos = offscreen_canvas.width

            time.sleep(0.05)
            offscreen_canvas = self.matrix.SwapOnVSync(offscreen_canvas)


# Main function
if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_text = RunText()
    if (not run_text.process()):
        run_text.print_help()
```

This gave me an error output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

argparse.ArgumentError: argument -t/--text: conflicting option string(s): -t, --text
```

What do I need to fix to get this to have multiple lines?  I have tried googling this but am unable to find a solution.

I am using an adafruit hat bonnet with a 128x32 LED panel.

Comment: Without also seeing the code for `SampleBase` it's unlikely anyone will be able to help you.

Comment: why do you add `add_argument("-t", ...)` two times ? It makes problem. You can get text with one `--text "line1;line2;line3"` and later split it to 3 lines with `split(';")`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to uses only one `add_argument("-t", ...)` and then you options

1) send all as one string

```
--text "line1;line2;line3"
```

and later uses `split(";")` to split it into lines

2) uses `action="append"`

```
add_argument("-t", "--text", action="append")
```

and then you can uses `--text` many times and it will create list with all values

```
--text "line1" --text "line2" --text "line3"
```

3) uses `nargs="*"`

```
add_argument("-t", "--text", nargs="*")
```

and then you can uses one `--text` with many lines without `;` but using space

```
--text "line1" "line2" "line3"
```

---

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-t1')
parser.add_argument('-t2', action='append')
parser.add_argument('-t3', nargs='*')

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.t1:
    args.t1 = args.t1.split(';')
print(args)
```

Use

```
./main.py -t1 "a;b;c" -t2 "x" -t2 "y" -t2 "z" -t3 "1" "2" "3"
```

Result

```
Namespace(t1=['a', 'b', 'c'], t2=['x', 'y', 'z'], t3=['1', '2', '3'])
```